# place else on new line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format, autoformatting

how can I place my else on new line, for example, I want to change

```
if () {
} else {
}
```

into

```
if() {
}
else {
}
```

I have edit the`C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style` and entered `{ BasedOnStyle:Microsoft, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}`

Comment: clang-format's Microsoft style uses [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style). Are you sure clang-format is being invoked?

Comment: I found that the format isn't invoked, but it do worked once, I don't know why it failed again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [vscode's formatter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting) uses [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) by default, so if you didn't change it, we can refer to the clang-format [options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) directly, can you try to append the following key-value ([BeforeElse](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#:%7E:text=bool-,BeforeElse,-Wrap%20before%20else)) pair within your braces?

```
BraceWrapping: [BeforeElse: true]
```

If that doesn't work, then you should try to use the traditional `.clang-format` file which vscode also supports.

Comment: I don't know why all the formatter don't work now, I've tried many ways, but the formatter never worked since then.........

Comment: now, it shows that "The 'clang-format' command is not available. Please check your clang-format.executable user setting and ensure it is installed."

Comment: You can checkout whats the location with `command -v clang-format` or `where clang-format` (Windows), install it if its not available, the extension comes bundled with it in its install directory as well